Wordpress - apply_filter(...) add_filter(...) issue
I am using a third-party plugin and a child theme. In the third-party plugin they are calling apply_filter('wc_epo_extra_addon_properties', $data) in my child theme I am calling add_filter('wc_epo_extra_addon_properties', 'adjust_addon_properties', 10, 2) but it is not triggering the add_filter in my child theme functions.php file. I think this is because the plugin is loading and running apply_filter before add_filter has time to add the new filter. I tried the call the add_action('muplugins_loaded',  and put the add_filter in that method, but the method is called and not calling my add_filter method. Please help. Thank you.

look this, hook of plugins and theme are set before the init hook : https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/wordpress-core-load/. are you sur that the apply_filter is not executed too early ?
